# color for label with different text asp net

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, html

I am creating a user control in asp net c#, I have a parameter which displays different text .

Here is what I have done so far.
Asp net mark up:

```
<span class="info-box-text"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="Parameter1" /></span>
```

code behind:

```
public partial class Dashboard1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                Parameter1.Text = Par;
            }

        }


        public string Par
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

User Control Code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="content Main_Content">
      <!-- Info boxes -->
      <div class="row">

          <uc1:DashboardTopTile1 runat="server" id="Dashboard1" Par="CPU Traffic" />

          <uc1:DashboardTopTile1 runat="server" id="Dashboard2" Par="Likes" />
          <uc1:DashboardTopTile1 runat="server" id="Dashboard3" Par="Sales" />
          <uc1:DashboardTopTile1 runat="server" id="DashboardT4" Par="New Members" />
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#Dashboard1{
background-color:green;
}
#Dashboard2{
background-color:blue;
}

#Dashboard3{
background-color:orange;
}

#Dashboard4{
background-color:red;
}
```

I want in my page each parameter text to have its own color but so far I get none color just white with text in it.

What am I doing wrong here? Any Suggestions? or is it posiible to do it in code behind using if statment if yes then how? Thanks

NB: Am a newbie !

Comment: Tip: open your broser Developer Tools page and check what the ID those `DashboardTopTile1` hav. Think: if you add the same `UserControl` multiple times then you will have duplicated IDs then ASP.NET has to make it somehow unique (adding _something_ to the ID you _suggested_). Easiest way in this case is, probably, to use classes instead of IDs.

Comment: Did you imported your CSS?

Comment: Ferus Yes I did

Comment: @Adriano Repetti I have tried everything but nothing , now am trying to use if statement behind the code :(